# Exception does not get caught

Tags: c++, exception

I have a base and a derived exceptions, public inner classes of store:

```
//base class - ProductException
    class ProductException: exception
    {
    protected:
        const int prodNum;
    public:
        //default+input constructor
        ProductException(const int& inputNum=0);
        //destructor
        ~ProductException();
        virtual const char* what() const throw();
    };

    //derived class - AddProdException
    class AddProdException: ProductException
    {
    public:
        //default+input constructor
        AddProdException(const int& inputNum=0);
        //destructor
        ~AddProdException();
        //override base exception's method
        virtual const char* what() const throw();
    };
```

this function which throws the derived exception:

```
void addProduct(const int& num,const string& name) throw(AddProdException);
void Store::addProduct( const int& num,const string& name )
{
    //irrelevant code...
    throw(AddProdException(num));
}
```

and a function which calls the function and tries to catch an exception:

```
try
{
    switch(op)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            cin>>num>>name;
            st.addProduct(num,name);
            break;
        }
    }
}
...
catch(Store::ProductException& e)
{
    const char* errStr=e.what();
    cout<<errStr;
    delete[] errStr;
}
```

The derived class should get caught, but I keep getting the error "unhandled exception". Any ideas why? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `AddProdException` is not a `ProductException`, because you are using private inheritance:

```
class AddProdException: ProductException {};
```

You need to use public inheritance:

```
class AddProdException: public ProductException {};
```

The same applies to `ProductException` and `exception`, assuming the latter is an `std::exception`.

Answer (score 4):

Without the `public` keyword, inheritance is considered [private](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html) by default. This means `AddProdException` is-not a `ProductException`. Use public inheritance like so:

```
class AddProdException : public ProductException
{
public:
    //default+input constructor
    AddProdException(const int& inputNum=0);
    //destructor
    ~AddProdException();
    //override base exception's method
    virtual const char* what() const throw();
};
```

Also, inherit from `std::exception` publicly in `ProductException` as well, otherwise you won't be able to catch `std::exception`s either (or even better, from `std::runtime_error`).